# was or were should be used in below examples?

Tags: grammaticality

earnings per share was  or earnings per share were - which is correct? Since, earnings per share is always a single number (not multiple number, not plural)  I used to use 'was', but back of my mind I have a fear that I may be wrong!!!

Comment: The doubt is because, it is 'earnings'  NOT 'earning' per share

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the metric, 'earnings per share', you would use the singular, as for example in:

> Prior to the issue of FRS3, earnings per share *was* defined as....

However, if you're talking about the value of this metric, then you would use the plural, because the number that ensues is generally in units of currency:

> Earnings per share *were* 0.96 euro

Looking at relative usage of 'were' vs 'was' in Google ngrams, the plural version appears several times more often than the singular.

[image]